# Add my UIView to a ViewController in Storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, storyboard

I am new in iPhone development.

I have a UIViewController in storyboard that includes a scrollView.

I want to put two UIImageViews and some UILabels on it.

the idea that I am thinking is : create a .xib file. Put a UIView on it, an then set my UIImageview and labels on this UIView.

Finally add my UIView which is a .xib file to my UIScrollView.

Is it a good idea? if not what is your suggestion.

until now I could not make it works. this is my code:

```
OfferUIView *newPageView = [[OfferUIView alloc] init];      // UIView that I created as .xib
self.newPageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
newPageView.frame = frame;
[self.scrollView addSubview:newPageView];
[self.pageViews replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:newPageView];
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
NSArray *views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OfferView" owner:self options:nil];
UIView *newPageView = [views lastObject];
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it sounds stupid, but have you tried removing the `self` from `self.scrollView` and `self.pageViews` ?

Answer (score 0):

How did you created your .xib file? it should be sub class of **UIView**. Hope you didn't do the mistake of creating it as a sub class of UIViewController.

Comment: No, it is definitely a UIView.

Comment: Check you OfferUIView.h file, is it UIView?

Comment: Yes as I said : @interface OfferUIView : UIView

Comment: Open you .xib file=> click on the parent view=> on the left bar click show identity inspector=>on custom class section in the field class check if its OfferUIView. Also the File's Owner is NSObject.